# list of permutations of HEADS and TAILS in n tosses with exactly k HEADS in Python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to write some python code to list the different permutations of heads and tails given n tosses and exactly k heads. E.g. for `n=6` tosses and `k=3` heads, the output that I want is `['000111', '001011', '001101', '001110', '010011', '010101', '010110', '011001', '011010', '011100', '100011', '100101', '100110', '101001', '101010', '101100', '110001', '110010', '110100', '111000']`
(Note: this is *not* a question about calculating probability, no issues there. My issue is with generating all of the different permutations for n tosses and exactly k heads).

I know that the *number* of final strings is given by the binomial coefficient aka combination aka n_choose_k (e.g. `scipy.special.comb`). However, I'm having trouble generating each of these different options for more than a modest (n>10) number of tosses. My first naive approach is to generate all possible permutations of a string such as `"1111100000"` (using `itertools.permutations`), and then I remove duplicates using `set()`. This works for low n (`n<=10`). However, this is crazy inefficient. Even with `n=10 & k=5`, the number of permutations is 3,628,800 while number of combinations is only 252. After `n>10` this grinds to a halt. I know that `itertools` also has `combinations` generator (and `_with_replacements`). However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use it to generate output in the way that I require, since my problem isn't exactly selecting a subset of k elements from a set of length n, where order does not matter.

My initial code is below.

```
from itertools import permutations
import scipy.special

n = 10
k = n//2
n_choose_k = scipy.special.comb(n, k)
print('{} choose {} = {}'.format(n, k, n_choose_k))

U,D = '1','0'
seed = U * k + D * (n-k)
permlist = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(seed)]
permset = sorted(list(set(permlist)))
print(permset)
print('len permutations:{}, len set:{}'.format(len(permlist), len(permset)))
```

Note: I'm interesting in n tosses and *exactly* k heads, though I would be curious to see how the solution could be expanded to *at least* k heads too.

---

### UPDATE:

I've accepted [karl-knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100745/214488). But for those curious, here are all three methods with run times (on laptop with i7-9750H @2.6Ghz)

### Results:

> ```
> 10 choose 5 = 252.0
> Permutations: 252 items. Calculated in 1.0340404510498047s
> Combinations: 252 items. Calculated in 0.00103759765625s
> Binary ints: 252 items. Calculated in 0.002962350845336914s
>
> 12 choose 6 = 924.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 924 items. Calculated in 0.001998424530029297s
> Binary ints: 924 items. Calculated in 0.023003339767456055s
>
> 14 choose 7 = 3432.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 3432 items. Calculated in 0.011020183563232422s
> Binary ints: 3432 items. Calculated in 0.10396194458007812s
>
> 16 choose 8 = 12870.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 12870 items. Calculated in 0.049001455307006836s
> Binary ints: 12870 items. Calculated in 0.42699623107910156s
>
> 20 choose 10 = 184756.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 184756 items. Calculated in 0.6319949626922607s
> Binary ints: 184756 items. Calculated in 7.8870697021484375s
>
> 22 choose 11 = 705432.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 705432 items. Calculated in 2.974030017852783s
> Binary ints: Gave up after 30 seconds.
>
> 24 choose 12 = 2704156.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 2704156 items. Calculated in 11.795861721038818s
> Binary ints: Gave up after 30 seconds.
>
> 26 choose 13 = 10400600.0
> Permutations: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> Combinations: 10400600 items. Calculated in 51.053600549697876s
> Binary ints: Gave up after 30 seconds.
> ```

### Code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations, combinations
import scipy.special
import time

n = 26
k = n//2

test_permutations = n <= 10
test_combinations = True
test_binaryints = n <= 20

test_print_outputs = n <= 6

n_choose_k = scipy.special.comb(n, k)
print('{} choose {} = {}'.format(n, k, n_choose_k))

U,D = '1','0'

def calc_permutations():
    seed = U * k + D * (n-k)
    l = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(seed)]
    return list(set(l))


def calc_combinations():
    '''Suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100745/214488
    '''
    def bit_strings(size, one_count):
        for one_indices in combinations(range(size), one_count):
            yield ''.join(U if i in one_indices else D for i in range(size))

    return list(bit_strings(n, k))


def calc_binaryints():
    '''
    Suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/users/9046247/aramakus
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100262/214488
    '''
    def check_bits(num, k, n):
        """ True if `k` ones inside the number.
        From https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100497/214488
        """
        return sum( (num & 2**rank)>>rank for rank in range(n)) == k
        
    def to_bin(i):
        return format(i, '0'+str(n) + 'b')

    start_int = 2**k-1
    end_int = 2**n
    l = [to_bin(i) for i in range(start_int, end_int) if check_bits(i,k,n)]
    return l


def test_method(name, fn, do_test, sort=True):
    print(name + ':', end='')
    if do_test:
        start_time = time.time()
        l = fn()
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        if sort: l.sort()
        print(' {} items. Calculated in {}s'.format(len(l), duration))
        if test_print_outputs: print(l)
    else:
        print(' Gave up after 30 seconds.')

test_method('Permutations', calc_permutations, test_permutations)
test_method('Combinations', calc_combinations, test_combinations)
test_method('Binary ints', calc_binaryints, test_binaryints)
```

Comment: neat edit :) could have put that up in a self answer as well, already upvoted your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use it to generate output in the way that I require, since my problem isn't exactly selecting a subset of k elements from a set of length n, where order does not matter.

It is, actually, with a bit of lateral thinking. The set you want to select from is the set of *indices* where a 1 should appear in a given output.

So: use `itertools.combinations` to determine the indices where the 1s should go (we are choosing `k` values from the `n` possible index values - `0` to `n-1`, inclusive - without replacement; that is exactly what combination are), and then generate the string for each. For example, as a generator:

```
def bit_strings(size, one_count):
    for one_indices in itertools.combinations(range(size), one_count):
        yield ''.join('1' if i in one_indices else '0' for i in range(size))

>>> len(list(bit_strings(20, 10))) # takes a bit less than a second on my machine
184756
```

This is, of course, still exponentially (literally!) slower than just calculating the number of combinations directly.

Answer (score 3):

Manifesting the whole list of permutations (as strings) is a big memory hog. You can use a modified version of @aramakus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100262/7505395) to push the boundaries of whats feasible a bit by using integers and a checker using bit-shifts to generate only those integers with `k` "ones":

```
def check(num, k, n):
    """ True if `k` ones inside the number."""
    # uses bit shifting and masking to get number of 1s
    return sum( (num & 2**rank)>>rank for rank in range(n)) == k

def pretty_print(l, n):
    """Pretty printer for list n (integer elements) padded to n digits"""
    for num in l:
        print((f'{num:0{n}b}'))
        # or without formatting mini language
        # print(('000000000'+bin(num)[2:])[-n:])

n = 15     # tested for up to 18 (which takes ~25s on my laptop)
k = n//2  
nums = [i for i in range(2**n) if check(i,k,n)]

pretty_print(nums,n) 

# total numbers is just 2**n, the amount of them with k ones is countable
print(f'exactly {k} ones: {len(nums)} out of {2**n} numbers')
```

Output:

```
000000001111111
000000010111111
000000011011111
000000011101111
000000011110111
...
111111001000000
111111010000000
111111100000000
exactly 7 ones: 6435 out of 32768 numbers
```

---

Ballpark calculation times using `time.time()` (so not repeated/averaged timings of multiple runs and most assuredly quite some measure of error involved):

```
 # You should do this using timeit.timeit() for serious measurements

 n   k   time in seconds
 5   2   0.0019998550415039062
 6   3   0.004002809524536133
 7   3   0.009006261825561523
 8   4   0.020014286041259766
 9   4   0.04403090476989746
10   5   0.09506702423095703
11   5   0.20834732055664062
12   6   0.4523327350616455
13   6   0.9736926555633545
14   7   2.0954811573028564
15   7   4.479296922683716
16   8   9.40683913230896
17   8   19.881306886672974
18   9   41.978920459747314

# somewhat "linear" calculation time
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to work. As an optimization, the range can start at 2**k-1, since that is garanteed to be the smallest int with k 1s. After n=20 it starts getting really slow :) (I haven't waited for it to finish yet!)

Comment: @memo good idea with the starting limit - there are only a "few" test cases excluded like that though, but it is a optimization non the less

Answer (score 1):

Not a fair solution, but you can calculate a `2**k-1` and write all integer numbers between 0 and `2**k-1` in binary format. This list would contain all 0s and 1s combinations with a total of `k` numbers.

Comment: A binary approach is a nice one (not generalizable to other situations, but potentially could address my specific question). But if I've understood this correctly, it seems to be something completely different. For one thing, where does n feature in this? And the constraint that there must be exactly k  1s?

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood your solution, I thought it it all the combination with `k` tosses. The fact that you count only to `2**k-1` insures that there will be only `k` numbers. I agree, a cute trick for a particular problem. For exactly `n` 1s and addition per-digit summation is required with a check whenever the `sum == n`.

Comment: yes this is an interesting approach. Actually, as an additional optimization, one could start at `2**k-1`, since that is garanteed to be the smallest allowable integer with `k` number of `1`s. So then it becomes a case of checking all integers between `2**k-1` and `2**n-1`. I'm not sure how efficient this will be, but I will try it out of curiosity, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think from the optimization standpoint it is not very optimal. It is essentially a brute force check, but generation will be quite fast as decimal to binary conversion simple.